# Binding a Text property for filtering within a popup that is part of a DataTemplate not working

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have an application that displays a datagrid. However the data has gotten big and I want to incorporate filters to some of the rows. I've gotten as far as creating a DataTemplate for my headers:

```
<DataGrid>
<DataGrid.Resources>
   ...
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <ColumnDefinition/>
             <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    <ToggleButton Name="FilterButton" Grid.Column="1" Content="▼" Margin="2, 1, 1, 1" Padding="1, 0"/>
                     <Popup IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=FilterButton, Path=IsChecked}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=FilterButton}" StaysOpen="False">
                     <Border Background="White" Padding="3">
                            <TextBox Text={Binding PetNameFilterSearchBox, Mode=TwoWay} Width="300"/> <!--The Text Box I want to bind-->
                     </Border>
                    </Popup>
             </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.Resources>
   <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="6*" Header="Pet Name" Binding="{Binding PetName}" ElementStyle="{DynamicResource DataGridTextColumnWrap}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource HeaderTemplate}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

So far what it does is show a button next to the header text and when you click on it a small popup window appears containing a text box. The desired effect is that the user can type in the text box and data will be filtered according to what was typed.

In my view model I already have my filter text box property that I want to use for binding:

```
public string PetNameFilterSearchBox
{
    get
    {
        return _petNameFilterSearchBox;
    }
    set
    {
        _petNameFilterSearchBox = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(PetNameFilterSearchBox));

        FilterData(); //As you're writing
    }
}
private string _petNameFilterSearchBox = string.Empty;

public CollectionView PetDataFilterView { get; set; }

public bool OnFilterTriggered(object item)
{
    if (item is AvailablePetInfo petInfo)
    {
        var pet_name = PetNameFilterSearchBox;

        if (pet_name != string.Empty)
                return (petInfo.DisplayName.Contains(pet_name));
    }
    return true;
}

public void FilterData()
{
    CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AvailablePetInfo).Refresh();
}  

//Constructor
public PetInfoViewModel()
{
   AvailablePetInfo = GetPetInfo();//gets the list
   ContactFilterView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AvailablePetInfo);
   ContactFilterView.Filter = OnFilterTriggered;
}
```

When I run my code I see the little button next to the header, I click on it and I see the textbox. But when I start typing I dont see my datagrid updating. I set some breakpoints in my PetNameFilterSearchBox and I find that when I start typing it's not getting hit. This tells me that there's something wrong with the binding. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is one of [`DataContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext).

I'll be assuming `PetNameFilterSearchBox` is a property of the `Window` hosting the `DataGrid` and that the appropriate `DataContext` is set at the `Window` level.

Normally, `DataContext` is inherited by child elements, so setting the `DataContext` for the `Window` would set it for all its children. But things change once you start using `DataTemplate`s.

In a `DataTemplate`, the root `DataContext` is always the data object that's being displayed. In your case, that's the string `"Pet Name"`. This is why you can put `<ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>` inside the `DataTemplate` and have it display `"Pet Name"`.

The downside is you can't put `<TextBox Text="{Binding PetNameFilterSearchBox}"/>` and expect it to bind to the `Window`, because that `DataContext` is being overridden by the `DataTemplate`.

Normally, you can get around the `DataTemplate` `DataContext` problem by using [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource), which you can use walk up the visual tree and find another source to bind to. But this doesn't work inside a `Popup` because a `Popup` is not actually part of the `Window`'s visual tree.

What *will* work is [`ElementName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.elementname):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding PetNameFilterSearchBox, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=W}" Width="300"/>
```

In the above example, I set on my `Window` `Name="W"`.